# How to get sibling td value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <asp:Label ID="lblUnitPrice" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UNIT_PRICE") %>' />
           <input type="text" id="txtUnitPrice" style="display: none" />
        </td>
        <td>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="linkBtnUnitPrice" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClientClick="SetEditMode(this); return false;" />
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get lblUnitPrice id when user clicks on linkBtnUnitPrice i.e in SetEditMode(this) function using JQuery or Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear; JQuery doesn't know anything about your ASP tags; it will only see the finished HTML code. In this case, I would expect your `<asp:Label>` should generate a single HTML tag, but that's not always the case with more complex ASP tags.

Your JQuery code should look something like this:

```
$('#linkBtnUnitPrice').click(function() {
    var label = $(this).parent().siblings().find('label');
});
```

however, given that you already know the ID of both the button and the label, you don't really need to be hunting for siblings; you can go straight to the relevant ID:

```
$('#linkBtnUnitPrice').click(function() {
    var label = $('#lblUnitPrice');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).parent().prev().find("input").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

adding this or something similar to the button would probably do the trick. (not tested myself tho.)

```
onclick="alert(jQuery(this).parent().siblings('td').children('label').attr('id'))"
```